# Switch Fields for my PhD

Tags: phd

#### Short General Question

> Is it possible to do a PhD in a **seperate field** apart from the field I had done my Undergraduate on ?

#### Detail Question

> I am a holding a degree in relation to Construction Industry, but I love to do a PhD in Remote Sensing which is totally seperate field from my undergraduate program. but I have self studied Remote Sensing and Machine Learning for over a year and half as well as done my M.Sc research project using applications of Remote Sensing. In addition I have a promising research idea on Remote Sensing and Machine Learning. **Thus is it possible to do a PhD in a totally different filed apart from the field I had done my undergraduate on.**

---

#### Background,

*I had completed my **B.Sc (hons) Quantity Surveying and Construction Management** with First class honors. Then I followed **MBA** and a **M.Sc in Water Resources Management** with 3.74 GPA*

*I had never followed Remote Sensing in my undergraduate program and only followed a one course module in my M.Sc as GIS and Remote Sensing and further studied it for my research project*

Comment: Do you want to use Remote Sensing as a technique to collect/analyze data related to Water Resource Managment/Costruction? then yes, it is certainly possible.
Do you want to develop new way of processing Remote Sensing data? more difficult, not impossible, you probably need a solid understanding of Signal theory (and therefore advanced calculus knowledge).

Comment: I am leaving both construction and water resource management fields. and yes it will be a rough journey. I am going to find a solution for an Agricultural issue with using Remote Sensing and Machine Learning where I had found while working unofficially in a research project due to Covid. my Idea is my original one and not even marginally related to the project I had worked in. I had done some tests on my own for over year and a half and they are giving very much promising results.

Comment: Having been exposed to different fields/topics is your strongpoint, not your weakness. Look for openings related to applying ML methods to agricultural issue (there is a lot of interest) and at the same time build your ML skills by following one of the 1000s online course on the subject (I suggest you the hands-on approach via Python or similar tools).
Good luck!

Comment: You can certainly apply to positions you find interesting, and might even get an offer. However, I think it is important to consider how difficult it will be to get up to speed to the topics of interest in the PhD.